# change height in specific row in a table (above the row, not below)

Tags: tables

As you can see in this horrible figure

[image]

the `^2` is too close to the line. I know I can use

```
row \\[1.2ex]
\hline
row
```

but it only adds space below the row, I need space above. Also I don't need to change the height in every row, only in one. How can I do it?

Comment: it's usually better to increase all rows in a consistent way eg `\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}` from the `array` package, but in one row you can use `\rule{0pt}{2cm}` which will increase its height

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to increase the row height of a single row, you could use `\addstackgap` from the `stackengine` package (which adds a buffer above and below the argument).  But as David mentions in the comments, a uniform approach, if possible, may look better.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{c|c}
Parameter Name & Error\\
\hline
\addstackgap{$X^2$} & 1.548\\
\hline
\addstackgap[10pt]{$X^2$} & 1.548\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]